# Is it possible to have multiple trigger options in jenkinsfile (cron , pollSCM , upstream)?

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I read the article here : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

but didn't find information to my q.

Is it possible to have something like this ?

```
  triggers {
  upstream(upstreamProjects: "Tester-Builder", threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
  cron('H H/1 * * *') // every 1 hour
  }
```

This is not working for me and I want to trigger the job in 2 conditions

```
(upstream project OR every 1 hour)
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: As the name applies you can define several triggers. What is not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when I put SCM first it didn't worked, when switched the order it worked.

```
  triggers {
  cron('H H/1 * * *') // every 1 hour
  upstream(upstreamProjects: "Tester-Builder", threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
  }
```